# Allow URLs without any extension with url rewriting, like exemple.com/forum

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to allow urls like `http://example.com/forum` on my website.

Here is my .htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Currently, I get a 404 error.

If I change `^([a-z-]+)$ /$1.php [L]` to `^([a-z-]+).html$ /$1.php [L]`, and my url `http://example.com/forum.html`, it works.

I want something like stackoverflow, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions`

EDIT: It works with WAMP in localhost, but on the website, it doesn't.

What's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# add .php file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule (.+) /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

1. I have added `Options -MultiViews` -- can make a big difference on some configurations (possibly your case).
2. Rule is now also checking if such .php file actually exist. If not -- no rewrite occurs.